# JS l Проблема с chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({["test"]:"okay"})
chrome.storage.sync.get(['test'], result => {
    console.log(result)
});
```

Начал недавно изучать js и столкнлулся с проблемой. Есть переменная test в chrome.storage со значением okay, мне нужно вывести лишь значение этой переменной в консоль, то есть, только okay, если выполнить код, который прикреплен выше, то получим следующее- [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Пробовал методы value,text, не сработало, что и не удевительно. Надеюсь, что смогу решить данную проблему. Заранее благодарю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читайте документацию https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
  console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
});

chrome.storage.sync.get(['key'], function(result) {
  console.log('Value currently is ' + result.key);
});
```